# How to disable "Transform to" option in Gutenberg custom blocks

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I prepared some non-standard Gutenberg blocks.

They have a very specific purpose. Therefore, I do not want them to have the `Transform to` option available.

What I found is the ability to use `support: {}`, but I can only disable `Add to Reusable blocks` there.

---

Can this option be blocked too? I can't find any information in Block Editor Handbook

By picturing, I mean this option:

[image]

Comment: this functionality represents an unfortunate design decision; who wants to deliver a product with non-applicable functionality holding such prominent space in the interface, did you find a solution?